# REST: HTTP PUT - Parent with Child Entities

Tags: rest, webapi

Is there a standard/convention in REST that dictates the expected behavior with respect to Child entities when I use an `HTTP PUT` on Parent record?

For example, the initial state of my `Parent` object is:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "children": [
      {"id": 1, ...},
      {"id": 2, ...},
      {"id": 3, ...}
   ],
   ...
}
```

And then I perform an `HTTP PUT` on `/parents`:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "children": [
      {"id": 2, ...}, // I changed a property in here
   ],
   ...
}
```

I would be inclined to update the Parent, and the Child with `id` 2, but are Children with `id`'s 1 and 3 supposed to be deleted or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a standard/convention in REST that dictates the expected behavior with respect to Child entities when I use an HTTP PUT on Parent record?

No

- REST doesn't have "entities" or "records".  It has "resources".
- REST doesn't have "children".  Common identifier spellings do not imply a relationship between two resources.

```
PUT /parents HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
   "id": 1,
   "children": [
      {"id": 2, ...}, // I changed a property in here
   ],
   ...
}
```

What this message means is "make the representation of the resource /parents match the body of this message".  In other words, save my copy of this document on top of your document.

In this case, it says that there should be exactly one entry in the children array, with id: 2.

How the server does that is an implementation detail hidden behind the REST facade.  The message only describes what the client wants, not what the client gets.  The server owns its own resources, and has a lot of freedom to choose how to modify them.  That could include deleting the underlying entities, or marking them as end of life, or removing them from the list without changing them, or even none of those things.

The server does need to be a little careful with its response, to be sure not to imply that the new representation matches the body of the request unless that's actually what it has done.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP and REST doesn't have a concept of 'children'. If you do a `GET` request on a resource and there's something called "children" there, then those children are basically just part of that resource.

A `PUT` request should replace the state of the resource. If you are replacing the list of children with a new list of children, then yes I would expect those changes to stick.

Comment: So what you're saying is, in REST the resource is always considered atomic. Right?

Comment: In HTTP the expectation is usually that requests either fully succeed or fully fail. I think that's what you are asking, and I would agree with that.